# Ajuda com Questionário moodle

Tags: moodle

Gostaria de criar um lista de usuários que por exemplo respondeu "não" a um questionário.

tem como eu selecionar esses usuários e enviar uma mensagem? gerar uma lista de usuários e importar, alguma solução?

tenho um questionário de 16 questões todos com 300 alunos, imagina selecionar um por um :/

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o plugin do tipo módulo de atividade / avaliação `mod_feedback` que aparece na lista de recursos do moodle como: `Pesquisa`. Os módulos de pesquisa possibilitam a criação de inquéritos ('survey') personalizados.

Caso ele não apareça na sua lista de "Atividades ou Recursos" dentro de um curso moodle, acesse como administrador, selecione o menu `Administração do site > Módulos de Atividades > Gerenciar atividades` e procure o plugin `Pesquisa` e habilite-o clicando no ícone semelhante a um olho humano.